# Problema al cargar imagenes con biblioteca Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje de programacion Python, haciendo ejercicios y reproduciendo codigos de ejemplo referente a cargar imagenes en interfaces graficas por medio de Tkinter en Sublime text3 y Sypyder, se genera el siguiente error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Danilo\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\Users\Danilo\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

  TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist
```

Este es el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x600")
ventana.config(bg="blue")
ventana.title("Ejemplo")

imagenL=PhotoImage(file= "escudo.gif")
LbLImagen1=Label(ventana, image=imagenL).place(x=100,y=100)
ventana.mainloop()
```

He tratado de reproducir diferentes codigos que sé que funcionan, he cambiado la extencion de las imagenes a pgm, ppm, y gif, he cambiado el tamaño de las imagnes y me sigue arrojando el mismo error 
Las imagenes estan guardadas en la misma carpeta,talvez sea un conflicto de bibliotecas pero toda la biblioteca de Tkinter funciona, excepto al cargar imagenes, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Modificar el nombre de la imagen no modifica el formato de la imagen como tal.
Abrela en paint -> guardar como `.gif`.

En tu error te dice que no existe `"pyimage5"`

```
TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist
```

Pero en tu codigo usas `"escudo.gif"`, al parecer no estas ejecutando ese codigo que pones.